# Time series database "metrics limit"?

Tags: database, time-series, graphite, graphite-carbon

I'd like to know if a time-series database will crumble with this scenario:

I have tens of thousands of IoTs sending 4 different values each 5min.

I will query those values for each IoT, for certain time spans. My question is:

Is a tsdb approach feasible and scalable up to, e.g.,  a million IoTs, having metrics like:

```
iot.key1.value1
iot.key1.value2
iot.key1.value3
iot.key1.value4
iot.key2.value1
.
.
.
iot.key1000000.value4
```

? Or are they way too much "amount of metrics"?

The retention policy will be 2 years, with possible roll ups maybe after (TBA) months. But I think this consideration only matters for disk size afaik.

Right now I'm using graphite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reporting frequency of five minutes that should be fairly manageable, just be sure to set your storage schema to five-minutes being the smallest resolution data in order to save space, as you won't be needing to hold on to data at shorter periods.

With that said, scaling a graphite cluster to meet your needs isn't easy as Whisper isn't optimized for this. There are several resources/stories where others have shared their dismay trying to achieve this, for example: [here](https://www.vividcortex.com/blog/2015/11/05/nobody-loves-graphite-anymore/) and [here](https://medium.com/teads-engineering/scaling-graphite-in-a-cloud-environment-6a92fb495e5)

There are other limitations to consider too, Whisper is configured in such a way that it can record only one datapoint per timestamp, and the last datapoint received "wins". This might not be an issue to you now, but later down the road you might find that you need to increase the datapoint reporting requency to get a better insight into your data.

Therein comes the question, how can I get around that? Often, **StatsD** is the answer - it's an aggregator that takes your individual metrics over a defined period of time, and churns out a histogram-like set of metrics with different statistical derivatives of your data (minimum, maximum, X-percentile, and so on). Suddenly you're then faced with the prospect of managing a Graphite instance or cluster, one (or more) **StatsD** service, and that's before you even get to the fun part of visualising your data: Grafana is often used here and also requires you to set up and maintain.

Conversely, assuming you will maintain that reporting frequency, but increase the number of devices (as you mentioned), you might find another component of your Graphite stack - Carbon-relay - running into some bottlenecking issues (as described [here](https://www.infoq.com/news/2019/03/graphite-scaling-booking/)).

I work at [MetricFire](https://www.metricfire.com/?utm_source=sof&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=graphite), formerly *Hosted Graphite*, where we had a lot of these considerations in mind when building our product/service. Collectively we process millions of datapoints per second across hundreds of accounts. Data is rolled up and stored at four resolutions: 5-seconds, 30-seconds, 5-minute, 1-hour, where each resolution is available for 24 hours, 3 days, six months and two years, respectively.

A key component of our set-up is that our storage is not built on the typical Whisper backend - instead we use a custom-built data store using Riak allowing us to do many things: scale easily and aggregate datapoints per metric into [Data Views](https://www.hostedgraphite.com/blog/advanced-data-views-better-observability-more-control?utm_source=sof&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=graphite), to name a few. That article about Data Views was written by one of our engineers and goes into some detail about the decisions we made when building our storage layer.